# Get the text present after a HTML tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a web page to obtain text that comes below a heading or bold text. For a web page with part of code like below, I wish to obtain the text present after the bold tag but before the h3 tag.

This is not same as the inner text of the tag. I do not wish to obtain text 'Name of instructor', I wish to obtain the details of the professor - name, designation, office hours.

```
    ....
    <bold>Name of instructor</bold>:
    Dr. A. B. C<br />
    Professor, Dept. of Alphabet<br />
    Office hours: M, T 8:00am-10:00am<br />

    <h3>Course Name</h3>:
    Introduction to Alphabet

    <h4>Course timings</h4>
    Monday 4:00-6:00 pm
    Tuesday 5:00-6:00 pm
    ....
```

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse the web page. I have tried using **.next_sibling** but that works for tags with same name, like bold for bold or h3 to h3. **.next** gives the next element and not next tag, which could be **br** or **p**

Please let me know if there is anything I could add to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using BS3. This code iterates along `nextSibling`s until it detects a non self-closing tag (like `<br />`), collecting all the found `NavigableString`s.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup, Tag, NavigableString

txt = \
'''
<bold>Name of instructor</bold>:
Dr. A. B. C<br />
Professor, Dept. of Alphabet<br />
Office hours: M, T 8:00am-10:00am<br />

<h3>Course Name</h3>:
Introduction to Alphabet

<h4>Course timings</h4>
Monday 4:00-6:00 pm
Tuesday 5:00-6:00 pm

'''

pool = BeautifulStoneSoup(txt, selfClosingTags=['br'])
found_txt = []
for x in pool.find("bold").nextSiblingGenerator():
    if isinstance(x, Tag) and not x.isSelfClosing:
        break
    elif isinstance(x, NavigableString):
        found_txt.append(x)
print found_txt
```

Given you have the full HTML (I presume), you won't need to use StoneSoup, just regular Soup.

Comment: Bummer. "BS4 does not respect the selfClosingTags argument to the BeautifulSoup constructor. The tree builder is responsible for understanding self-closing tags."